# How to show remote push notification as a banner style in active state of app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

I am making an app in which I am using apple push notification. When my app is in background state then I am able to receive notification as a banner but when my app is in active state then I am able to show an alert that you have received a notification through this code : -

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {    
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {

        NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
        NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
        NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some title"
                                                            message:message 
                                                           delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];
        [alertView show];

    } else {
        //Do stuff that you would do if the application was not active
    }
}
```

but I want to show notification as a banner. What I'll do for it? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, if your app is active(running in the foreground) the push notification is directly send to your app. The notification center will not handle the notification.

You will have to implement some kind of banner your self.

Comment: On iOS 9, the Mail and Messages apps show the standard notification banner UI for new emails and messages in some situations. Is there a new API to replicate this, or are they using private API?

Comment: My guess, private API. Since I can't find it in the documentation. But you can create something very close to the native one yourself.