# UIApplication didReceiveRemoteNotification, show an in-app banner

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to show an in-app banner notification during my app's game play, not my current `UIAlertView`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{    
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
         // Show Alert ->
         // UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Did receive a Remote Notification", nil)
         // message:[apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"]
         // delegate:self
         // cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
         // otherButtonTitles:nil];
         // [alertView show];
         // [alertView release];

         // Show Banner Notification
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFnmj.jpg]

How would I implement an in-app banner notification during my app's game play?

Comment: What have you tried? A `UIView` with a multi line `UILabel` is what I suggest

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show remote push notification as a banner style in active state of app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601533/how-to-show-remote-push-notification-as-a-banner-style-in-active-state-of-app)

Comment: Thank you. troop231. It was good for me.

Comment: Not quite the same as the one You've posted, but there's nice github project: https://github.com/toursprung/TSMessages also available as cocoapods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define BANNER_HEIGHT 66.0    

  if (!showingNotification) {
        showingNotification = YES;

        // retrieve message from your actual notification here
       NSString *message = @"Showing notification";

        UIToolbar *newmessageBannerView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -BANNER_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, BANNER_HEIGHT)];
        newmessageBannerView.translucent = YES;

        newmessageBannerView.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        newmessageBannerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 33.0, 16.0, 16.0)];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_72"];
        [newmessageBannerView addSubview:imageView];
        [self.view addSubview:newmessageBannerView];

        UILabel *bannerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 30.0, 320.0, 22.0)];
        bannerLabel.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        bannerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        bannerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        bannerLabel.text = message;
        bannerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
        bannerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        [newmessageBannerView addSubview:bannerLabel];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             newmessageBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, BANNER_HEIGHT);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                              animations:^{
                                                  newmessageBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -BANNER_HEIGHT, self.view.frame.size.width, BANNER_HEIGHT);
                                              }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                  [newmessageBannerView removeFromSuperview];
                                                  showingNotification = NO;
                                              }];
                         }];
    }
}
```

I try Test iOS 6.0, 7.04, 7.1.